# Relation between cyclotomic character and fundamental character of level

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

The question I have is the following: is it true that the $p+1$ exponentiation of the fundamental character of level $2$ gives us the reduction (mod $p$) of the cyclotomic character?
For a review of the definitions, see [here](http://planetmath.org/sites/default/files/texpdf/37525.pdf).
Thank you for yours answers.

Comment: Definition 1 in that link is "wrong": fundamental characters of all levels on inertia groups of $p$-adic fields $K$ are defined in a unified manner. Read about it early in Serre's 1972 Inventiones paper on torsion on elliptic curves.  The correct definition of the level-1 fundamental character makes it *the same* as the $(p+1)$th power of any level-2 fundamental character. So the question is really if the level-1 fundamental character is the mod-$p$ cyclotomic character. For ramified $K$ this can be false. For $e=1$ it is true and a consequence of Wilson's Theorem in elementary number theory.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Serre proves in his paper that the niveau 1 character to the power $e$ (absolute ramification index) is the cyclotomic character.

Comment: The link to `planetmath.org` is broken. I am also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine. Perhaps the content has been moved here on PlanetMath: [fundamental character of level $n$ for the inertia group at $p$](https://planetmath.org/fundamentalcharacteroflevelnfortheinertiagroupatp)